# Unpainted object

Tags: dynamic-paint

I'm painting letters with a series of key frames.  As the brush nears the top the painting stops.

I've tried changing the size of the brush, the paint source from volume to volume + proximity. but it seems to run out of paint at a specific frame.  What is the explanation for what is happening?

[image: Why is this letter not being painted]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the Canvas setting, where I had to change the last frame which is 250 by default and my final frame was 350. Did not see that because I was key framing the brush